# How to get id_token from refresh token issued by Google OAuth 2.0 Playground?

Tags: oauth-2.0, cypress, e2e-testing, google-authentication, google-api-js-client

I trying to solve the problem with E2E testing and Gapi.js. So I created an ENV variable and handle Cypress differently if the environment is testing.

In order to achieve it, I need to get `id_token` somehow - with Gapi.js help or by the direct API call. What I have is: `client_id`, `client_secret`, `refresh_token`. After POST to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` I get `access_token`.

How can I get the final token with this data? Or there's any other way to E2E test signup with Google API library?